# PHP - json_encode and array size

Tags: php, json

[PHP version 5.5.9]
I have an array similar to the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(5) "Item1"
      ["price"]=>
      int(999)
      ["img"]=>
      string(38) "http://someu.rl"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["title"]=>
      string(5) "Item2"
      ["price"]=>
      int(1999)
      ["img"]=>
      string(38) "http://someu.rl"
    }
  }
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

When I use `json_encode()` on this array I have no problems until the array contains 4 (or more) items. Then it returns false instead of the JSON string. 
I once exported the array (with 12 items) using `var_export()` and inserted it manually into `json_encode()` (originally the data is from a database) and then it worked.
Has anyone an idea what the problem is? Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: Well then some error happened. What is the output of: `echo json_last_error_msg();` if you put it right after `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Returns a JSON encoded string on success **or FALSE on failure**.

There is a 99.99% chance, that your "longer" string contains unescaped characters or other invalid stuff.

There is no "limit" in the size of an json array, neither does `json-encode` have. (Beside natural system limitations, which you wont hit with 4 elements)

Comment: I already set the table charset to UTF-8 but somehow forgot to also set the connection charset to UTF-8 too. Works now.